# Request Input and Response Logging in Kotlin Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc

Is it possible to log requests in kotlin spring mvc? I tried using content caching wrappers. I am able to see the request input in the logs but the request responses are empty. Is there something that I am missing or I will have to use spring webflux with kotlin to achieve this?

```kotlin
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class RequestLoggingFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {
        val startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
        val requestWrapper = ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request)
        val responseWrapper = ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response)
        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper)
        logRequest(startTime, requestWrapper, responseWrapper)
    }

    private fun logRequest(
        startTime: Long,
        request: ContentCachingRequestWrapper,
        response: ContentCachingResponseWrapper,
    ) {
        log.info(
            "$REQUEST_LOG",
            kv("$REQUEST", String(request.contentAsByteArray)),
            kv("$RESPONSE", String(response.contentAsByteArray)),
            kv(
                "$REQUEST_TIME",
                StringBuilder()
                    .append(Instant.now().toEpochMilli().minus(startTime))
                    .append("ms"),
            ),
        )
        response.copyBodyToResponse()
    }

    @Throws(ServletException::class)
    override fun shouldNotFilter(request: HttpServletRequest): Boolean {
        return EXCLUDED_URLS.contains(request.requestURI)
    }

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestLoggingFilter::class.java)
    }
}
```